# How to return status `Skipped` in self defined pre-commit hook?

Tags: bash, git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

I have a self defined pre-commit hook which I want to skip if an earlier hook fails. If an earlier hook fails, a logfile named `pre-commit.log` is generated.

A `.pre-commit-config.yaml` could look like this:

```
repos:
-   repo: https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8
    rev: 3.9.2
    hooks:
    - id: flake8
      log_file: pre-commit.log
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    - id: skript
      name: skript
      entry: bash skript.sh
      language: system
      log_file: pre-commit.log
```

My bash `skript.sh` looks like this:

```sh
if [ -f "pre-commit.log" ]; then
  echo "Error in earlier pre-commit! We skip this script."
  echo "See 'pre-commit.log' for detailed information."
  exit 1
else
  echo "All pre-commits successful."
  # some other code
fi
```

Right now I check if the "pre-commit.log" exists and if so I return `exit 1`. Because of this, the output for this hook is `Failed`. But I would prefer the status `Skipped` because there was no failure.

My goal is to see in the console or logfile the text `Skipped`, like in this image for `jupyter-notebook-cleanup`.
If I write `exit 0` I get `Passed` like for `isort` and `black` and if I return `exit 1` or another number greater 1 I get `Failed` like for `flake8`.

[image: console output]

How can I get the message `Skipped`?

Comment: If you want a hook to be skipped, it seems you simply want it to return 0 so git considers it to have passed.  How do you want git to behave when your hook is "skipped"?

Comment: If I return `0`, the check is `Passed`. Since an earlier hook is failed, git will reject the commit anyway.

Comment: What is "check is Passed"?  git does not report status at all.  It just rejects the commit.  If you want a status line that says "skipped", then write `if test -f pre-commit.log; then echo "Skipping pre-commit hook"; exit 0; fi`

Comment: Ah...you have edited the question.   What framework are you using that is generating that status report?

Comment: I am using a terminal on a Linux machine calling `git commit "message"`. I follow the process descripted [here](https://pre-commit.com/index.html#usage).

Comment: Looks like those scripts do not support your feature: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/blob/master/pre_commit/commands/run.py#L199-L204. It should be an easy change to make. Submit a PR!

Comment: Note that all of that status reporting is coming out of your hook scripts.  git knows nothing about it, and doesn't care about anything other than the status code returned by the script.

Comment: That sounds very plausible. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The test suite built by the autotools followed the convention that 77 was the return code for a skipped test.  If you do submit a PR, I would recommend following that convention.

Comment: Ah....but look here: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/blob/master/pre_commit/commands/run.py#L134. Perhaps the functionality you seek is already there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no way to influence that text be `Skipped`

`Skipped` only appears in the following cases:

- the hook was not run because its hookid appeared inside the `SKIP` environment variable
- there were no files which matched `files` / `types` / `types_or` and `pass_filenames` was `true` (the default) and `always_run` was `false` (the default)

your best bet is to `exit 0` in the non-failure case, this will appear as `Passed` in the output

---

disclaimer: I wrote the pre-commit tool you're using

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would you accept a Feature Request like @William Pursell
mentioned with the code `77`? Or is this something you see no benefit?

Comment: no, pre-commit can run any executable and it cannot guarantee the conventions of any executable follows some arbitrary "77" code